# Python 3 dynamic class attribute

Tags: python, object, for-loop, attributes

Hi everybody I'm trying to change an attribute in a for loop, like:

```
user.project_0   mitarbeiter.percent_0 
user.project_1   mitarbeiter.percent_1 
user.project_2   mitarbeiter.percent_2 
...



for x in range(10):
    for mitarbeiter in user.select().where(user.project_0 == projektnummer):
        # timedelta object
        working_time = ((mitarbeiter.gehen_1 - mitarbeiter.kommen_1) + (mitarbeiter.gehen_2 - mitarbeiter.kommen_2))
        complete_time += (working_time.seconds / 100) * mitarbeiter.percent_0
```

i tried with setattr() and type() but i cant figure it out.
Thanks for help!

Comment: Are you using some kind of an ORM?

Comment: yep i'm using peewee and user.project_0 relates to an entry in a database

Comment: yes, you can set attribute by name with `setattr`: `setattr(object, name, value)`. Like `setattr(mitarbeiter, 'percent_%s' % x, complete_time)`. But use it with caution, especially with ORM because attributes you set should reflect real database columns.

Comment: your problem is that you are not using update ... also, can you show what you tried with setattr

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to use getattr() and format the string.

```
for x in range(10):
    for mitarbeiter in user.select().where(getattr(user, 'project_{}'.format(x)) == projektnummer):
        working_time = ((mitarbeiter.gehen_1 - mitarbeiter.kommen_1) + (mitarbeiter.gehen_2 - mitarbeiter.kommen_2))
        complete_time += (working_time.seconds / 100) * getattr(mitarbeiter, 'percent_{}'.format(x))
```